# How to convert a string path to a tree (hierarchial path)

Tags: c++, data-structures, trie

I am trying to insert a string path into a trie data structure, But I am not able to make relation between child and root. it looks like I am not inserting
element into proper way into trie.
For ex. /AB/CD/DE
1. first I insert AB ( which work correct)
2. when I tried to insert CD AB overwrite with CD

I am doing mistake during creation of Trie. I am trying to achieve following way

```
AB
 \
  CD
  / \
 DE EF
```

My input is a absolute Unix path like this:

> /AB/CD/DE
>
> /AB/CD/GH

```
Output of below program 
processing path /AB/CD/DE 
processing path /AB/CD/FG 
AB 
CD
Segmentation fault
```

so I can easily convert into a trie.

```
  #include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<queue>
#include<vector>
#include<boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include<boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include<utility>
#include "Command.h"
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

struct Dirinfo {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string,Dirinfo*>>list;
    bool leaf_node;
};

class Dirmapping {
    private:
        Dirinfo *root = nullptr;
        std::vector<std::string> dirs;
    public:
        Dirmapping() = default;
        Dirmapping(const std::vector<std::string> &dir_name);
        Dirinfo* getnode();
        Dirinfo* getchild(Dirinfo *tmp, const std::string &dir_name);
        void createmap();
        void display(Dirinfo *root);
};

Dirmapping::Dirmapping(const std::vector<std::string> &dirs): dirs(dirs) {
    root = getnode();
}

Dirinfo* Dirmapping::getnode() {
    Dirinfo *node = new Dirinfo;
    node->leaf_node = false;
    return node;
}

Dirinfo* Dirmapping::getchild(Dirinfo *tmp, const std::string &dir_name){
    for(auto it = tmp->list.begin(); it != tmp->list.end(); ++it){
        if(it->first == dir_name){
            it->second->leaf_node = false;
            return it->second;
        }
    }
    tmp->list.push_back(make_pair(dir_name, getnode()));
    tmp->leaf_node = true;
    return tmp;
}

void Dirmapping::createmap() {
    Dirinfo *temp = root;
    for(auto it = this->dirs.begin();  it != dirs.end(); ++it) {
        std::vector<std::string> split_string = Command::split_path(*it);
        std::cout<<"processing path "<<*it<<std::endl;
        for (auto split_it = split_string.begin(); split_it != split_string.end(); ++split_it){
            temp = getchild(temp, *split_it);
        }
    }
    display(root);
}

void Dirmapping::display(Dirinfo *root)
{
    if (!root->leaf_node)
        std::cout<<root->list[0].first<<std::endl;

    for(auto it = root->list.begin(); it != root->list.end(); ++it){
        if (it->second) 
            display(it->second);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> dir_names;
    dir_names.push_back("/AB/CD/DE");
    dir_names.push_back("/AB/CD/FG");
    Dirmapping dirmap(dir_names);
    dirmap.createmap();
    return 0;
}
```

Command.h

> command.h which do split of string using "/"

```
namespace Command {
inline std::vector<std::string> split_path(const std::string &f_path) {
        std::vector<std::string> token_string;
        boost::char_separator<char> split("/", "\n");
        tokenizer tok(f_path, split);
        for(tokenizer :: iterator it = tok.begin(); it != tok.end(); ++it) {
            token_string.push_back(*it);
        }
        return token_string;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you program in C++, then please don't add irrelevant language tags.

Comment: Besides that, [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? What is getchild supposed to return? Does it do the same thing on both branches?  What actually happens and what did you expect instead?

Comment: updated question

Comment: Can you expand this into a complete example with some hardcoded input that isn't working? When you say AB is replaced by CD, where does that happen? Seems like it's in the code we can't see.

Comment: updated question

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger allows you to single step through your program, *watching* values in variables (and tracing flow of execution).  Often, debugging your program is faster than correctly posting to StackOverflow and *waiting* for somebody to inspect or debug your program for you.  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.